# Python 3.6 - Do I Need To Use A Loop, Or Something?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I'm making a script that asks the user to enter a number, and depending on the number, it prints a specific answer. The issue I'm having is, I'm not sure how to make it so they can just keep entering in different numbers after it prints, and see the different answers. I'm new to Python, and I'm not sure if a loop is what I need to use, and how I would even do it. 
In regards to my code, I have a lot more then 5 answers, but I just shortened it so its easier to read. Right now, the only way I can enter different answers, is to enter one, have it print the answer, close it, open it again and enter a different number. Th script itself works fine, I'm just looking for a way to go through all the numbers without having to keep running the script every time I want a different answer. If someone could please help me, I'd appreciate it. Thank you.

```
print ("Welcome.")

var = int(input("Please Enter A Number: "))

if var == 1:
    print("Hi.")
if var == 2:
    print("Hello.")
if var == 3:
    print("Yes.")
if var == 4:
    print("No.")
if var == 5:
    print("Answer.")

k=input("Press Enter To Close")
```

Comment: Yes. You need to use a loop.

Comment: Yes you need a (while-)loop to surround the whole thing, to make it repeat. Typically people do `while True: ...` and `break` inside the loop if you ever need to exit it. And as for converting the input integer into the corresponding string, you could use an `if...elif...else` ladder (clunky) or a dict as @hansaplast shows (more elegant and compact).

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use an infinite loop to ask for a number without having to run the code again:

```
print ("Welcome.")

def enter_number():
  var = int(input("Please Enter A Number: "))
  if var == 1:
      print("Hi.")
  if var == 2:
      print("Hello.")
  if var == 3:
      print("Yes.")
  if var == 4:
      print("No.")
  if var == 5:
      print("Answer.")

while True:
  enter_number()
  play_again = input("Do you want to play again (yes / no)?")
  if play_again == "no":
    break
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'd need a loop. What what you're also looking for is a `dict` (aka map) which lets you convert the number into the string. Something like this:

```
print("Welcome.")

while True:
    var = int(input("Please Enter A Number: press Ctrl-C to quit"))

    number_to_string = {1: 'Hi.', 2: 'Hello.', 3: 'Yes', 4: 'No.', 5: 'Answer.'}
    if var in number_to_string:
        print(number_to_string[var])
    else:
        print('unknown')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
answers=["Hi","Hello","Yes","No","Answer"]
while True:
    number=input("Please Enter a Number:")
    if number=="": break
    print(answers[int(number)-1])
```

Comment: This is bad style and incorrect. a) You don't need to explicitly declare `numbers`, just use `enumerate(answers)`. Cleaner and simpler. b) You're confusing a while-loop to keep polling user for input, with a for-loop to iterate over each possible answer once, then stop (why? that's not what the OP wanted). c) Anyway you're not doing anything with `pair` from `for pair in ...`, you just ignore it and lookup `answers[number-1]`

Comment: Better, but in this case it's probably better style to be explicit and use a dict `number_to_answer = {1: 'Hi.', 2: 'Hello.'... }` rather than a list where the numbering is implicit, (@hansaplast's answer). Oh and that also avoids the clunky `int(number)-1` kludge that zero-based indexing forces on you.